# Passing a list of URLS from one page to another

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

On the index page of my Django site I generate a list of urls that allow the user to navigate to a detail page. Once the detail page appears the navigation is no longer visible.

What I am trying to achieve is that the navigation list appears on the detail page (and every page that is added to my site).

What I have tried is the following: (the first line in each view is duplicated)

```
def index(request):    
    **collection_urls = Collection.objects.order_by('the_year')**    
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'collection_url': collection_urls})

def originalexample(request, collection_id):
    **collection_urls = CarCollection.objects.order_by('the_year')**    
    car = get_object_or_404(CarCollection, pk=collection_id)    
    return render(request, 'detail.html', {'originalexample': car, 'collection_url': collection_urls})
```

Whilst this works, I know it is not right as I running the query twice. My next thought would be to perform the query once and then pass it to the pages as they are rendered. If so how would I do that? or is there a more pythonic method?

In case of need I'm using Django 1.6.2 and the list of urls does not change frequently (They can only be changed via the Django admin screens)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to pass them from one to another, you simply want them to appear everywhere. That is usually done via [context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) or [custom tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-template-tags/).